Value of nested dict remains unchanged in loop
Consider the following:
template = {"first": "John", "last": "Doe", "numbers": {"age": 30}}
people = []
for age in range(30, 41):
    new_dict = template.copy()
    new_dict["numbers"]["age"] = age
    people.append(new_dict)
people

This will output:
[{'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}},
 {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'numbers': {'age': 40}}]

Instead of age taking the value of each item in the ages list. However, if the age key is not nested in numbers, then it will get each value.
Why is that? What should I do instead?

Search for deepcopy. Without using a deep copy, every copy is just  copying the same reference to the same nested dictionary.

Got it, thanks! :-)

.copy() only makes a new copy of the outer "container" object.  The items inside the container are the actual object references.  They are not copies.
